# SQL Server 2008 Installation move from C to D

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a client that has SQL Server 2008 installed on their C drive which is 39GB (0.5GB free disk space left), and I want to move this to D: which is 180GB (160GB free).

I know you can change the installation path to D:\ on a clean install but I was wondering if this was possible to move the destination path for the database files from C:\ to D:\ without having to re-install SQL Server 2008.

I can take their databases offline and copy and move the database files, I am just hoping I can change the directory as it would save a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to move the databases' mdf and ldf files or the SQL Server executables and dlls?

The DBs are easy.  A) detatch the DB, move the files and attach again *or* B)  take a backup and `RESTORE .. MOVE <logical file> <path on D drive>` (check books online for the full syntax).

You can also set the [default path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for new databases created by `CREATE DATABASE`, but really you should provide the full file name when you do this anyway.

The executables would be tricky bordering on impossible without a reinstall.